# Validate attributes through edmx

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, ado.net-entity-data-model, edmx

I'm working on an MVC3 project I have created my database on SQL server 2008 then I add it using entity data model, now I have the .edmx I don't want to generate the code of the classes because till now it's not stable and I don't feel the need to do that except to make the validations
I'm wondering if there is a way to make validation directly using the .edmx without generating the code of classes
Need server and client side validation
Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do it from edmx. You can however have classes that add the metadata to the edmx generated classes.

This adds a metadata containing class to the class that was generated by the edmx:

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(CustomerMetadata))]
public partial class Customer
{
}
```

and then you have the metadata class which has the metadata attributes:

```
internal sealed class CustomerMetadata
{
    public int ID;

    [Required]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string Name;
}
```

**Edit:**
EF generates all it's classes as partial. That means you can add functionality in a different file to the same class. We use this feature to add an attribute telling .net that there's a class that has the metadata information. In this case the class with the metadata for the `Customer` class is `CustomerMetadata`.

It has all the properties that you want decorated with metadata. In this case ID is not actually required to be there.

Comment: So I have to add a partial class in the model folder with the same name of the table and I make validation on the attributes using the MetadataTypeAttribute. I don't know if I understand well how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

(I would have added this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation points yet)
Be sure that the namespace in your partial class exactly matches the EF-generated class's namespace, including the correct case.